# go-swagger: command not found

Tags: go, homebrew, go-swagger

Trying to install go-swagger on Ubuntu.
I have installed brew(Linuxbrew):

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Linuxbrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Next I did:

```
brew tap go-swagger/go-swagger
brew install go-swagger
```

typing `swagger version`
it answers: swagger: command not found.
anything else(-help, -version not working too)
What I did wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
git clone https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger
cd go-swagger
go install ./cmd/swagger
```

Verify using:

```
swagger version
```

Answer (score 0):

Running `brew tap go-swagger/go-swagger && brew install go-swagger` and then re-running command `go-swagger` worked for me. Any more details that can be provided here?

This command may also assist you, since you're utilizing `go` already... might be problematic if utilizing go modules or not.
`go get -u github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/cmd/swagger`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `$GOPATH/bin` in your path reason why it cannot find the it

Potential fix:

```
echo 'export PATH="${GOPATH-"~/go"}/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc 
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score -1):

To install go-swagger run below command in GO PATH

```
go get -u github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/cmd/swagger
```

To check the version and help run

- `swagger version`
- `swagger -h`

Comment: nothing happens when i run this command. So i had to use ctrl+c to stop it.